# geometry surface area and cubes

Tags: geometry

a cake is formed in the form of a cube of side 20 cm, coated from all the sides with chocolate. If one corner of the cake is cut by a plane through midpoints of the edges meeting at the corner find the area without chocolate.

Comment: Where is your attempt? If you haven't attempted, why should we?

Comment: Try drawing a diagram (and uploading it here).

Comment: The area is of isosceles triangle with side... you could find easily.

Comment: Equilateral triangle, actually.